# getting highest number on a textfile

Tags: c#

So i have this kind of a simple snake game and i am willing to have a label with a text: "High score" And then another label after it with the highest number of score it can find from a textfile.

```
string lines = " \r\n" + SnkScore.Text;            
File.AppendAllText("C:\\Users\\" + System.Environment.UserName +"\\Documents\\Data\\Scrn.txt", lines);

HghScore.Text = lines;
```

"Scrn.txt" is a text file which contains all the points that user has ever got in the snake game.

"SnkScore" is a label that has the current amount of points, and the "HghScore" is the highscore label where i am willing to load the highest value of "Scrn.txt" which has all the points user has ever got. So
restarts it would show the highest value of the textfile on the "HghScore" label.

Comment: Are the scores on separate lines?

Comment: why not use a proper database (sqllite) or a file format made to store numbers and semantic data (csv, xml)?

Comment: It's not efficient to always reread the whole file. You'd rather store the HiScore in a separate file and overwrite it on every GameOver if the record was broken

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Linq:

To get just one max number:
solution 1:

```
var max=File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\score.txt").Max(m=> m.ToInt());
```

solution 2:

```
 var max=File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\score.txt").Select(int.Parse).Max();
```

If you want a bunch of them then  sort it and Take x number from top:

```
var topFive=File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\score.txt").Select(int.Parse).OrderByDescending(m=> m).Take(5);
```

Personally, I would use TryParse in this scenario though, so manually going through each line and "TryParsing" this would be better.

Comment: +1 your answer is very small and accurate , i think i should start learning `Linq` :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the score.txt file will never contain an invalid score, you canuse LINQ (make sure that there's a `using System.Linq;` statement):

```
int maxScore = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\score.txt")
                   .Select(s => int.Parse(s))
                   .Max();
```

If you want to make your program more robust, the following program will convert
invalid lines to 0:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace HighScore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] scores = {
                "78",
                "98",
                "88",
                "77",
                "Bad score",
                "124",
                "3",
                "678",
                "4",
                "123",
                "456",       
            };
            //scores = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\score.txt");

            int maxScore = scores.Select(line => {
                int score = 0;
                int.TryParse(line, out score);
                return score;
            }).Max();

            Console.WriteLine("Maximum score is {0}", maxScore);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 your answer is very small and accurate , i think i should start learning `Linq` :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :** assuming that each score is in `New-Line`.

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String [] lines= File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\score.txt");
            long max = 0;
            long score=0;
            foreach (String line in lines)
            {
                if (Int64.TryParse(line, out score))
                {
                if (score > max)
                    max = score;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Maximum Score is "+max);
        }
```

**Input File :** `c:\score.txt` with following `scores`:

> 78
>   98
>   88
>   77
>   124
>   3
>   678
>   4
>   123
>   456

**Output :**

```
Maximum Score is 678
```

Comment: My snake scores are so awesome they wouldn't even fit in an Int32.

Comment: then you could use `Int64`.

Comment: Better yet you could use `int.TryParse` and let the platform decide.

Comment: @Lee: `int.TryParse` is `Int32.TryParse`, there's no "let it decide" on the output datatype.

Comment: @LeeHiles: see my edited answer, i changed it to work with `long`(Int64) types, i think that should be fine for you.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh, well then I learned something new. I was always under the impression that the runtime resolved `int` based on the processor architecture (as is done at the unmanaged level) where as `Int32` is an explicit 4 bytes.

Comment: @Lee: nope, The `int` keyword in C# *always* maps to a  32-bit integer.  There's no C# keyword for the MSIL `native int`, although most arithmetic operations end up using `native int` after compilation.

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi Thank you my friend, you have just saved my school project and my day!